# How to put a vertical line down center of bootstrap column under a font awesome icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a column using bootstrap where I have a font awesome icon. The height of each div can vary slightly so I need the line to adjust to the height of the div. I have come across many examples to place the line down the center of the div but all I can find are ones that cause the line to go through the icon. I would like to have the line start under the icon.

I would show you an example CSS but I really don't have anything I can show you. I don't even know where to start.

```html
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
</div>
```

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it wrapping your `i` element, then use a `css` pseudo-element to print out your line.

```
    <span class="vertical-line-icon" >
      <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
    </span>
```

Then the `CSS`:

```
.vertical-line-icon {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
.vertical-line-icon:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #555555;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rn9g21fj/

Answer (score 0):

may be try something line this? dividing eaahc section with bootstrap's row?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: center !important;">
<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760">  </i><br>
<img src="straight-line.jpg" />
</div> 
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1" style="text-align: center !important;">
<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760">  </i><br>
<img src="straight-line.jpg" />
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css's pseudo-element `::after`. Just make a block after the `i` tag and align it in center using `position:absolute;`

```css
i {position: relative;}
i::before {font-size: 30px;}
i::after {content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 120%; transform: translateX(-50%); width: 6px; background: #556e79; height: 180px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
```

Comment: This worked for the first column on top but after that the line goes from top to bottom through the rest of the font awesome icons

Comment: You don't want to add line to all the font awesome icons..!

Comment: I do, but not through the icon and not on top of it

Comment: I think the problem is occurred due to another css rule of your file, can you show me the problem on live demo please..! :)

Comment: I have no css related to any of those classes. Since they are bootstrap I leave them alone

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use CSS to make line vertical and to adjust the icons. I have used `class="row"` to make lines separated

I gave it a try and created a codepen aswell [CodePen Vertical Line](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLGXKN)

```css
vr { 
    
    width:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    bottom:0;
    left:15px;
    height:100px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i><vr />
</div>

<div class="col-sm-1">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
    <vr />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
    <vr />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
    <vr />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #5fb760"></i>
    <vr />
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Almost but it is causing a line to appear above the font awesome icon as well